# stress test video streaming

Tags: hosting, video-streaming, load-testing, stress-testing

is there a way to stress test video streaming? 
Basically simulating a high number of people simultaneously streaming a video?

This is an amazon 'cloud' service that will be enabled for my site.

Comment: Make an awesome video. Put it on your site. Hope it goes viral. ??? Profit.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the streaming protocol it is hard to recommend a specific solution.  If it is a Flash-based service, there are some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685311/how-do-i-load-test-a-flash-application).

If not, and depending on [if it is supported](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html), you could use VLC from the commandline to spawn a bunch of clients.  If you disable actually displaying the stream, you should be able to launch many clients per host to simulate a larger number of users.

[This page](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html) has some details on streaming from the command line.  For example, you could duplicate the stream and then set the display to `noaudio` and `novideo`.  Or, duplicate it to a file and redirect it to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

We had to write our own 'VoD-Basher' code to simulate our workflow based on our client interface, DRM and encoding options - there was nothing out there to do what we needed, not for the volumes we needed to simulate (>600k users) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the unicast and multicast streaming test tools in IxChariot.   The tests are network focused, not application focused, so if you are trying to test the load on your streaming server then IxChariot is not the tool you need.   If, however, you have a large question mark on your network infrastructure for how many streams your network can support in either a unicast or multicast model then IxChariot can help.

[IxChariot web site](http://www.ixchariot.com)

I don't sell it.  I don't service it.  I just find it to be an enormously cool and useful tool.